# GCP IoT connection Timeout - 10s

Tags: google-cloud-platform, iot

I'm using GCP for my IoT project. I'm trying to connect to IoT Core but the server has a 10s timeout. I connects with use GSM network so is very slow and I can't make transaction in 10s with using TLS protocol. Is possible to change timeout for more time than 10s?

Best regards!
Patryk

Comment: Can you elaborate on the error message you are seeing?  Maybe a snippet of code on how you are connecting and what error indication you are finding.  Are we sure that the timeout isn't happening at the client/caller rather than on the GCP IoT Core server?  What language and library are you using?  Are you using HTTP or MQTT?

Comment: No error. Server close socket after 10s. GCP server has only 10seconds for handshake in tls - but in my gsm network is to little time to negotiate tls. Im sure that is problem on server side. Im using tcp with tls to handshake. After handshake i will use http. Library is mbed_tls. I tested it on WiFi and all works good because on WiFi communication is faster and handshake use less time than 10s.